# How we compare the two following integral without calculation?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence

compare the two following integral without calculation :

1)$\displaystyle{\int_0^1x{e^{x^2}}dx}$

2)$\displaystyle{\int_0^1 \sqrt{x}{e^{x}}dx}$

I would be interest for any comments or any replies

Comment: Compare $xe^{x^2}$ and $xe^x$ on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Compare $x$ and $x^2$ over $[0,1]$.

Comment: sorry , see i edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $x^2 \leq x$ for $x \in [0,1]$, so $e^{x^2} \leq e^x$, next $x \leq \sqrt{x}$ (because $\sqrt{x}(\sqrt{x}-1) \leq 0$ for $x \in [0,1]$ so $xe^{x^2} \leq \sqrt{x}e^{x}$ and finally $\int_{0}^{1} xe^{x^2} dx \leq \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x}e^{x} dx$

Answer (score 0):

Note that on the interval $[0,1]$,  $x^2\leq x$. Since $e^x$ is monotonically increasing, it follows that on the interval $[0,1]$, $e^{x^2}\leq e^x$. You can then compare the two integrals.

Comment: @rafik thank you for your edits!